# How to change the Icon of a MFC-Application without changing each sub-image?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, mfc, icons

when I open the application icon of a MFC-project with Visual Studio 2008 there are 13 images (different sizes, different color palette). How would you change the icon of your MFC-application without changing each image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to use the [Icons file type extension](http://www.evanolds.com/pdn.html) with [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net). When you open a .ICO file it will prompt you for which image to open - select only the largest / highest-bit image. Make your changes, and then save. You will be prompted for which sizes and bitness to save - select the same list that was present in the original icon.

Using this method, you will get automatically scaled and dithered icons at the smaller sizes. A designer would actually tweak the icons at each size to get the best look, but for most applications this technique produces something that is usable.

Comment: nice tip. Didn't know of this extension. I use IcoFx mostly.

Answer (score 3):

An icon resource typically contains many different versions of an icon. For an application icon you would expect 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 and 256x256. You'd also expect to see the 3 smaller ones at 32 bit colour, 8 bit colour 4 bit colour. Or some variant on that.  Microsoft publishes [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx).

Why so many different versions of the same icon?

Well, the icon will be drawn in different settings. On a window caption bar, the 16px version will typically be shown. On the Windows 7 taskbar the 48px version will be shown. When usint ALT+TAB in XP the 32px will be shown. In Vista/7 explorer with ultra large icon view, the 256px will be shown.

To obtain the best visual appearance you must have different versions of the image for different sizes because small raster images aren't easy to scale. What's more, you may present a slightly different version of the icon at different resolutions. For example you may use 3D effects only on larger resolution, partial transparency versions.

When using remote desktop, lower colour depths may be used if the connection is bandwidth challenged.

The MS guidelines go into these issues in detail.

The normal practice of for the graphic designer to design the icon and once you are happy with it the designer will produce rasterised versions for all the required sizes and colour depths, typically in a single .ico file.

Comment: Thanks for the link and your explanation. It shows me that Icon creation is not a trival part and I should pay more attention on it. For the moment I get along with the tool suggested by Aidan.